# Elevator on rails

Tags: building, design, snot

I'd like to build an elevator for my apartment building.  My plan is to use [rails](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4510&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%208%20with%20Door%20Rail&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) and [grooves](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=90291#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)  to allow the elevator to slide up and down.  This means I have to build the elevator with the studs facing forward instead of up.  I'd like to have 4 rails on each corner of the elevator and slide them along grooves outside the elevator.
Here's some pictures of what I've built so far:

[image: Elevator car (click to enlarge)]
[image: Alignment problem (click to enlarge)]

The problem is that because of the dimensions, I can't quite get the grooves and rails to line up with eachother.  How do I calculate a set of dimensions for the elevator that will allow it to attach to 2 pairs of grooves.  I supposed I could use just 1 pair of grooves in the middle, but I think that would be less stable.

Comment: Not an answer, but check out the elevator in https://brickset.com/sets/10224-1/Town-Hall, as seen in https://images.brickset.com/sets/AdditionalImages/10224-1/10224_Back_02.jpg. This can give you ideas how to get the elevator to "stop" at a floor with a few Technic bits.

Comment: Another elevator you could check out would be in the [Ninjago City](https://brickset.com/sets/70620-1/NINJAGO-City).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like to keep your build studs up and avoid dealing with the 6:5 ratio, you could try to use [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Arm Up](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4623b&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Arm%20Up%20(Horizontal%20Arm%20Length%205mm)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C) with the already mentioned [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 x 5 with Groove](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=90291#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D), as the 3.18 mm bar will slide in the groove just fine.

[image]

---

Another option would be to keep the rest of the elevator car studs up, and only turn sideways for a few smaller rail pieces, like these: [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Handles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3839b&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Handles%20-%20Flat%20Ends,%20Low%20Attachment&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Lego bricks are not sized similarly in each dimension. The height to width ratio of a brick is 6:5, which means that 2 bricks stacked on top of each other with their studs up are 6 plates high, but the same 2 bricks stacked on top of each other on their sides (studs facing sideways) are only 5 plates high. Said differently, bricks placed sideways (studs to the side) align correctly with a regular brick pattern every 6 sideways placed bricks.

Use these facts to plan your rails and grooves.

Comment: Based on this, moving the rail to the other end of the stack of red plates (and moving the grooves 1 stud towards the front) *should* work, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjL67.png)